# how to dynamically position a "pop up" chart in react / tailwind

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I am working on a project in my spare time which is a basic financial analysis app for personal use.

I am using react / tailwind and have the following code to generate my charts:

```js
{isShown && selectedRowIndex !== null && selectedRow && (
selectedRowIndex === rowIndex ?

<div id='chart-container' className='fixed bg-white m-\[2rem\] my-\[-6.5rem\] z-20'>

<BarChart labelData={dts} dataInputs={row} /> </div>: null)}
```

As you can see from the picture below the basic layout is a line item followed by a chart icon which when you hover over you get a pop-up chart. However, when you are at the bottom end of the page the chart disappears into the never (you can sorta scroll down and see it but it's very broken). The line items are generated from a loop/map function so it's dynamic.

What I would like is that when you are on the top rows of the table the chart is positioned to the right and slightly below the line item and as you go further down it becomes more central and as you go further down past the center point of the table they get positioned slightly above the line item.

[image]